# Running tests on staging and dev with AWS Device farm

Tags: automation, aws-device-farm

I'm migrating my tests on AWS Device farm and need to run them with dev/staging that are available only through VPN.
I was using "Local Testing" feature from BrowserStack for this. Does AWS provides something similar to this or setting up VPN is the only way?